# How do a get the data from Haxe's http.customRequest without crashing?

Tags: haxe

Forewarning: I’m very new to Haxe.

I’m trying to use http.customRequest (with the intention of later making PUT and DELETE requests). But when I try to access the result bytes I get a segmentation fault with C++ and a NullPointerException with Java.

I’ve googled for some other uses of customRequest, and what I’m doing doesn’t seem wrong, but clearly it is.

```
class Main {
    static function main() {
        var req = new haxe.Http("https://httpbin.org/put");
        var responseBytes = new haxe.io.BytesOutput();

        req.onError = function(err) {
            trace("onError");
            trace(err); // Java says NullPointerException
        };

        req.onStatus = function(status) {
            trace("About to get bytes");

            // Removing these lines prevents the errors
            var b = responseBytes.getBytes();
            trace("Got the bytes");
            trace(b.length); // Shouldn't be empty, but is
        };

        req.customRequest(false, responseBytes, null, "PUT");
    }
}
```

I’ve tried this with the current release and with HEAD (via Brew).

I think my command lines are pretty basic:

```
$ haxe -cp src -main Main -java bin/java
$ java -jar bin/java/Main.jar
src/Main.hx:12: About to get bytes
src/Main.hx:16: Got the bytes
src/Main.hx:17: 0
src/Main.hx:7: onError
src/Main.hx:8: java.lang.NullPointerException

$ haxe -cp src -main Main -cpp bin/cpp
$ ./bin/cpp/Main
src/Main.hx:12: About to get bytes
src/Main.hx:16: Got the bytes
src/Main.hx:17: 0
[1]    54544 segmentation fault  ./bin/cpp/Main
```

In case it’s useful, here’s the differently broken output for Python:

```
$ haxe -cp src -main Main -python bin/Main.py
$ python3 bin/Main.py
onError
True
About to trace err
SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1045)')
```

I’d really appreciate any guidance. TIA

([Reposted](https://community.haxe.org/t/getbytes-crashing-after-http-customrequest/1048) from the Haxe forum, where I haven't had a response.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite an interesting interaction there, here's what happens in order:

- `sys.Http` receives the response and calls `onStatus()`.
- You call `responseBytes.getBytes()`, which ends up invalidating the internal buffer in `haxe.io.BytesBuffer.getBytes()`. The docs of that method state "Once called, the buffer can no longer be used", as it sets the internal buffer `b` to `null`.
- The `Http` class then attempts to write to that same buffer, which is no longer valid.
- Since there's a catch-all around the entire logic, the `onError()` callback is called due to the null reference.

The status code passed to `onStatus()` is 200 (OK), so apart from the `getBytes()` call, the request seems to work as expected. And according to [apitester.com](https://apitester.com/), `data` is empty for this particular request.

Comment: Once the `getBytes()` call is moved out of the `onStatus()` handler to below the `customRequest()` call, it works much better. Thanks.